# How can i get the id chosen from getItemAtPosition using a listview

Tags: android

I was working with a spinner and everything was working fine but i wanted to use a listView now and i can't send the id chosen in putextra because it's null.
This is my class

```
  // list func
    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // String folder = lst.getItemAtPosition( lst.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

            String folder = (String) lst.getItemAtPosition(i);

            String id = lstMap.get(lst.getSelectedItemPosition());



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Vous avez choisis "+ id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String newReq= new StringBuilder().append(AppConfig.URL_GetFoldersFK).append(id).toString();
            Log.d("Request show",newReq);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuildingsListActivity.class);
            // Sending value to another activity using intent.
            intent.putExtra("FolderId", newReq);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And here where i retrieve all of my data and i stock the id in a hashmap in order to use in my code above

```
   // list function

    private void loadListFolders (String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String dossier = jsonObject1.getString("nom");
                        String id = jsonObject1.getString("id");

                        lstMap.put(i,id);
                        Folders.add(dossier);

                    }

                    // spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Folders));
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                            (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Folders);

                    lst.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to retrive the id from the hashmap:

```
HashMap<int, Object> obj = (HashMap<int, Object>) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
String name = (String) obj.get(i);
Log.d("Yourtag", name);
```

Comment: I updated my code for you to get what i mean, i have a list of folders and when i click on one and i get the selected object, but now i want to get the id of the selected object which is stored in a hashmap

Comment: @koreangirl try now, if not work probably you are putting a wrong integer value in lstMap.get() try to put i intead of lst.getSelectedItemPosition()

Comment: Oki- i'll try it now, the problem is everything was working fine when i was using a spinner but now with a listview i don't know whatt's happening